# How determine the week number of a date when there is month overlap?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

There are a few questions like that, but none that takes in consideration the month overlap.
I need to generate weekly Payrolls, and because of that I can't use the normal calendar month range (1-30, 1-31, 1-28, etc) to refer to a given week.

The solution I found was to structure months like this:

First day= First Monday

Each week = 7 days

1 month = 4 weeks

And to know which week of which month a date belongs to, I'm trying to create a formula with this logic:

[Had to add an image, because Stack Overflow understand it as a code and don't let me post unformatted code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzrjR.png)

And this is the formula I'm trying to come up with to do that, being A6 a date:

```
 =SE(A6<=FIMMÊS(A6,-1)+MOD(8-DIA.DA.SEMANA(FIMMÊS(A6,-1),2),7),DATA(ANO(MOD(8-DIA.DA.SEMANA(FIMMÊS(A6,-1),2),7)),MÊS(MOD(8-DIA.DA.SEMANA(FIMMÊS(A6,-1),2),7)-1),DIA(MOD(8-DIA.DA.SEMANA(FIMMÊS(A6,-1),2),7))))
```

But I'm stuck at this part that should subtract the month:

```
MÊS(MOD(8-DIA.DA.SEMANA(FIMMÊS(A6,-1),2),7)-1)
```

Example:

input date: 02/15/2023.
Output month: February.
Output week number: 2.

input date: 03/05/2023.
output month: February.
Output week: 4.

I'm open to better ways of calculating week numbers with month overlaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try with this approach, substracting the day of the week beginning from Monday, from the input date. That divided by 7 is the amount of weeks, and the month is the one from that same calculated date:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",{"",""},{ROUNDUP(DAY(A2:A-WEEKDAY(A2:A,3))/7),TEXT(A2:A-WEEKDAY(A2:A,3),"MMMM")}))
```

[image]

Comment: Much better approach. Kudos

Comment: This is almost perfect, but it'll output weeks number 5 when it should restart the counting to 1. Someone suggested me this =SWITCH(MOD(ISOWEEKNUM(A1), 4), 0, 4, MOD(ISOWEEKNUM(A1), 4)) . It also solved it, so I'm leaving here for others who might find it helpful. Thanks!

Comment: But in your logic, if every 1st Monday starts a new month there will be months with 5 weeks. In that case I guess that we won't be included in the payroll. Consider you have 48 weeks in your logic and 52 in the actual calendar, if you don't consider the 5th week you will be offsetting too much from the actual months

Comment: Thanks, I'll check for any inconsistencies in the payroll and run some more tests before a problem happens. Ty

Answer (score 0):

This will return 1 to 4 weeks for every month, starting weeks at monday.

```
=SWITCH(MOD(ISOWEEKNUM(A1), 4), 0, 4, MOD(ISOWEEKNUM(A1), 4))
```